# Controller + Route + View

Tags: php, laravel

I am stuck concerning the display...When I launch I have the error messag "Whoops, something went wrong on our servers"

I have a Controller named **StaticViewController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Session;

class StaticViewController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('static.index');
    }

    public function getService()
    {
        return view('static.services');
    }

}
```

In my route I have that

```
Route::get('/', 'StaticViewController@index');

Route::get('/services', 'StaticViewController@getService');
```

Then, in View I have a folder named Static inside I have index.blade.php and services.blade.php

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is it fresh installation of laravel?

Comment: "_in View I have a folder named Static_" Have you tried naming your folder `static` (lowercase)? And, if you only want to display a view, there are [View Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#view-routes)

Comment: i think in .env file debug is false, for show error message change it to true

Comment: whats your error message? check .env file and set APP_DEBUG=true and APP_ENV=development. this should show the error message

Comment: Additionally to @SalarBahador s suggestion you should look into your log files for exceptions (storage/logs/laravel.log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

Please check you created `static` folder in `yourproject/resources/views` path

if yes then run below command in your `terminal` or `cmd`

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```